# What is a more efficient way to prevent actions from firing twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having an issue when someone taps the rightBarButtonItem on the navigation bar and taps it again quickly that the program crashes.  It's understandable that is crashes because the new view hasn't finished loading yet and the button is still visible to tap again so it will attempt to push the view again crashing the program.  I've tried a couple of methods to try and prevent this and my current implementation somewhat works, but I know there is a better solution, perhaps a solution built into the framwork?

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithTitle:@"Members" 
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                               target:self 
                                               action:@selector(showRoster)] autorelease];
}


-(void) showRoster {
    if (seconds + 3 < [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) { //This is where I am trying to prevent the button from being activated twice.
        seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

        vcRoster = [[RosterDataViewController alloc] init];
        vcRoster.rosterDataModel.group_id = self.tweetsByGroupIdModel.group_id;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcRoster animated:YES];
    }
```

}

I've also tried this, but it's not doing what I am thinking it should be doing.

```
if (!self.navigationController.isBeingPresented)
```

I've tried solving the problem and Googling my way to an answer, but I have yet to find a good solution to this problem.  I know the above is not a good way to do things, I'm open to suggestions for any improvements at all as I am extremely new to the IOS world.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try disabling the button as soon as the action method is run:

```
-(void) showRoster:(UIButton*)sender {
  sender.enabled = NO;
  ...
}
```

You can enable it later, to make it responsive again. How you can best do that depends on the view you are showing: if it is full screen, you might simply re-enable the button in `viewDidAppear:` (i.e., after the view has disappeared and your button is visible again).

Comment: I assume I need to pass some information with the selector, because when I used your code I get this error.

-[TweetsByGroupIdViewController showRoster]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b5d20

Comment: is that method on that controller? And is it a UIControl that is calling it?

Comment: Yes it is on that controller and I believe as in the code I have posted it is a UIBarButtonItem.  I took that into account when trying it in my code.  However it as if the sender argument is not seen because I assume the argument is not being passed.

Comment: Since you added the sender argument to this method, do I need to change the action selector in loadView to represent this somehow?

Comment: Wow that was silly, this whole thing lead me to realize that the navigation bar behind my button is the actual culprit, the navigation bar has a double tap that is actually causing the crash.  However your code does work for disabling the button properly, so this is the correct answer.  Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: you are welcome, and glad to know that by digging into this you could find the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIViewController's isViewLoaded method to check if the view has been loaded:

```
if (self.navigationController.topViewController.isViewLoaded && seconds + 3 < [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) {...}
```

Comment: I tried several variations of this code you posted, but none of them prevented the action from attempting to push out the view controller twice.